# Преобразование ссылки с определенным доменом в текст

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть html:

```
звіту про товарооборот торгової мережі (<a href="211707">форма № 1-торг (місячна)</a>) за липень 2016 року (<a href="http://my.site.ua/scion/document/default/MCFRxcb15f7livl0745fdspr7hilf4/(WKRU_MCF_306618)565F427A9613822271BC899C:WKRU_MCF_306618%23teid-3/19A0B43EB1D216C91ECDDDDF59EA0825:-%7Bxe96q7nimqcssk7mp9s0ia859n%7D?cfu=default&amp;cpid=ua-site-kadri&amp;uAppCtx=RWI" target="_blank">наказ Держстату від 11.12.2015 № 355</a>)
```

Необходимо ссылки которые ведут на сайт my.site.ua преобразовать в текст, но в тоже время что бы другие ссылки (которые ведут НЕ на my.site.ua) остались ссылками, что бы в итоге получился вот такой html:

```
звіту про товарооборот торгової мережі (<a href="211707">форма № 1-торг (місячна)</a>) за липень 2016 року (наказ Держстату від 11.12.2015 № 355)
```

Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью preg_replce, но почему-то не выходит. Получается вот такой результат:

```
звіту про товарооборот торгової мережі (наказ Держстату від 11.12.2015 № 355)
```

Использую вот такую регулярку:

```
$text = preg_replace("!<a.*?href=\"?'?http:\/\/my.site.ua([^ \"'>]+)\"?'?.*?>(.*?)</a>!is","\\2",$text);
```

В тестовых примерах и с другим html все работает корректно, а с рабочим html нет.
Подскажите, где ошибка? Что делаю не корректно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте регулярку

```
<a[^>]*?href=[^>]*?https?://my\.site\.ua[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

Конструкции `[^>]*?` и `[^>]*` использованы для того, чтобы перебор не выходил за пределы открывающегося тега и не убегал на другой тег `a`.
И вы в своей регулярке не экранировали точки.

Код

```
$text = preg_replace('%<a[^>]*?href=[^>]*?https?://my\.site\.ua[^>]*>(.*?)</a>%is', '$1', $text);
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/qB9uT1/1